# HTML and CSS code not working as expected

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on creating a simple card design using HTML and CSS. Here's the basic design:

[image: Screenshot]

So far this is my code:

```css
.map-drawer-item {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background: #EEE;
  color: #797979;
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 700;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.map-drawer-item-header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.map-drawer-item-status {
  margin: 0 1rem;
}

.map-drawer-item-header h5 {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.map-drawer-item-sub {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #797979;
  margin-left: 2.6rem;
  margin-top: -1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.map-drawer-item-icon-more {
  position: absolute;
  right: 1rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="map-drawer-item">

  <div class="map-drawer-item-header">
    <span class="map-drawer-item-status">
      <img src="empty.svg" alt="" srcset="">
    </span>
    <h5>AT-TP279 - SOme name</h5>
  </div>

  <div class="map-drawer-item-sub">
    <span>1692 km / 07:50</span>
  </div>
  <span class="map-drawer-item-icon-more">
    <img src="more-icon.svg" alt="" srcset="">
  </span>
</div>
```

This code isn't functioning as expected. For instance, when there is a long title, it doesn't work well. Is using Flexbox the right approach, or should I consider an alternative solution?

Thank you all for your assistance.

I want to maintain a consistent and flexible card layout, even when dealing with long titles. Furthermore, I would like to keep the 'more' icon in a fixed position

Comment: Please narrow down your problem and define the "consistent and flexible card layout" more precisely. How should long text behave, what shall happen when there is too much content? What happens instead? The code should be a minimal StackOverflow code snippet (much like CodePen), see how to produce a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
      .map-drawer-item {
        border-radius: 0.25rem;
        background: #eee;
        color: #797979;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 0.875rem;
        font-weight: 700;
        padding: 2rem 1rem;
        max-width: 300px;
        display: flex;
        gap: 16px;
      }

      .map-drawer-item-header {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .map-drawer-item-header h5 {
        font-size: 1rem;
        font-weight: 900;
        color: #585858;
        margin: 0;
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      .curcle-icon {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        border: 1px solid rgb(129, 129, 129);
        border-radius: 100%;
        margin-top: 3px;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .arrow {
        height: 10px;
        width: 10px;
        background-color: black;
        margin-top: 6px;
        margin-left: auto;
        flex-shrink: 0;
      }

      .text-box {
        display: flex;
        gap: 16px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="map-drawer-item">
      <div class="curcle-icon"></div>
      <div class="map-drawer-item-header">
        <h5>AT-TP279 - SOme name</h5>
        <span>1692 km / 07:50</span>
      </div>
      <div class="arrow"></div>
    </div>
```

please check if this is good for you. you just have to play with the margin-top for those icons to stay aligned with the text. or you can just remove the margin then it will align on top.